# What does "ampersand operator" mean between a class and a variable?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code in plumed and am quite confused:

```
void ActionAtomistic::makeWhole() {
for(unsigned j=0; j<positions.size()-1; ++j) {
    const Vector & first (positions[j]);
    Vector & second (positions[j+1]);
    second=first+pbcDistance(first,second);
  }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what "&" is used for here?  I googled "c++ ampersand between class and variable" but did not find the answer.

Updated: I know what reference is but thought there should not be any space between Vector and "&".  Thank you guys for clarifying that.

Comment: It represents a type of `Vector&`. It's a reference type. More on the subject: [reference declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: `I googled "c++ ampersand between class and variable" but did not find the answer.` Interesting. First google result of search with exactly that query leads to the answer.

Comment: "*thought there should not be any space between Vector and "&"*" - whitespace doesn't matter in this case.  `const Vector& first`, `const Vector &first`, `const Vector & first`, they are all the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that `first` is a **reference** (in this case, a `const` reference) to an object of type `Vector`, rather than an object of type `Vector`.

Read more about references [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/).

Answer (score 2):

That is known as a reference. I usually write references like `Type& name` to make it clear that the reference is part of the type.

References are like pointers that are easier to use but come with some restrictions. Here's an example of when you could use a reference:

```
void add1ToThisNumber(int& num) {
    num += 1;
}
// elsewhere...
int myNumber = 3;
add1ToThisNumber(myNumber);
cout << myNumber; // prints 4
```

Comment: I agree that reference is part of the type. However, for variables and members, I prefer to stick the `&` to the name (whenever multiple identifiers may be listed after a type. Example: `int& var1, var2;` may let you think both are references but that's wrong. It's actually `int &var1, var2;` and the second style makes this clearer. (IMHO) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (in this case) is basically an alias to another variable. While the following doesn't apply in the first case (as your reference is `const`), references can be used to modify the objects they are referring to. As an example:

```
int c = 5;
int& d = c;
d = 12; // c is set to 12
```

In your particular case, the reference is an immutable alias, so `positions[j]` cannot be modified through `first`.

In the second case, doing `second = variable` will evaluate to `positions[j + 1] = variable`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` has different meanings based on context.

1. Declare a type.

   ```
   int var;
   int& ref1 = var;           // Declares a reference to a variable
   int const& ref2 = var;     // Declares a const reference to a variable

   int& foo();                // Declares foo() whose return type is reference to an int
   void bar(int&);            // Declares bar whose argument type is reference to an int

   struct Foo
   {
      int& bar;              // Declares bar to be member variable of the
                             // class. The type is reference to an int
   };
   ```
2. Take address of a variable (any lvalue really)

   ```
   int var;
   int* ptr = &var;           // Initializes ptr with the address of var

   int arr[4];
   int* ptr2 = &(arr[3]);     // Initializes ptr2 with the address of the
                              // last element of arr
   ```
3. Perform bitwise AND operation.

   ```
   int i = <some value>;
   int j = <some value>;
   int k = (i & j);          //  Initializes k with the result of computing
                             //  the bitwise AND of i and j
   ```

What you have in your code is the first use.

```
const Vector & first (positions[j]);
```

That line declares `first` to be a `const` reference to `position[j]`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning `int arr[4]; int(&ref)[4] = arr;` as well

Comment: @KillzoneKid, it sure is an interesting case but won't by useful to the OP, IMO. If they don't understand the simple declaration, adding a reference to an array as an example would be too much, I think.