# Operator-oveloading dereference for a queue C++

Tags: c++, queue, operator-overloading

I am creating a queue with a class that iterates through the nodes.

To do this i will need to overload the dereferencer and "++" so i can write an iteration.

But i dont really get how to get back what I want from the overloading. I get flags all the time.

These are the two classes:

```
typedef Person Item;
class Node;
class QIterator
{
private:
    Node *node;
public:
    QIterator(); // default
    QIterator(Node *n); // initialized
    Item &operator*() const;
    QIterator &operator++(); // prefix ++i
    QIterator operator++(int); // postfix i++
    bool operator!=(const QIterator &qi) const;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class QList
{
private:
    Node *first, *last;
public:
    QList() :first(nullptr), last(nullptr) {};
    ~QList() {};
    void enque(Item item);
    bool deque(Item &item);
    bool del(Item item);
    bool isEmpty()const;
    QIterator begin()const { return QIterator(first); }
    QIterator end() const { return QIterator(nullptr); }
};
```

And here is the public class for the nodes:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node *next;
    Item data;
    Node(Node *n, Item newData) : next(n), data(newData) {}
};
```

What i have problem with is the overloading.

Item &operator*() const; is thought of getting back a reference to the data that is in the node that the datamember "node" is pointing at. The datatype should be Item &.

```
Item &QIterator::operator*() const 
{

    return &Item;
}
```

The overloading:
QIterator &operator++(); is thought of to return a reference to what *this points at after "++" has been excecuted. The datatype should be QIterator &.

```
QIterator &QIterator::operator++() {

    node = node->next;

    return *this->node;
}
```

This thing with pointers is really something I want to understand since i can imagine how much faster a program gets by using it. How should i think to understand this and remember how it works.

The overload QIterator operator++(int); should returns whats inside the node that the iterator points at before "++" is executed. It returns dataype QIterator

```
QIterator QIterator::operator++(int) {

    return this;

    node = node->next;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item &QIterator::operator*() const 
{
    return &Item;
}
```

is wrong since `Item` is a type, not an object. Even if `Item` were an object,  `return &Item` would be wrong since that would evaluate to a pointer. What you need is:

```
Item& QIterator::operator*() const 
{
    // return a reference to the item that the node points to.
    return node->data;
}
```

---

```
QIterator &QIterator::operator++() {

    node = node->next;

    return *this->node;
}
```

is wrong since the return type does not match the type of the expression used in the `return` statement. You need to use:

```
QIterator& QIterator::operator++() {
   node = node->next;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: So an asterix will still give me back a reference? What i have understood about pointers is that Item *item, is an adress to an Item, while as &item is a reference of what is inside of that adress. Have i misunderstood it?

Comment: @Newbie2018, It seems to me that you are confused about the operators `&` and `*`. See couple of my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938113/434551 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36962697/434551. Hopefully they will clear some doubts in your mind.

Comment: Yes I feel really confused about this :'D. Your posts were very informative. After reading them I am pretty sure that i have written the third operator wrong too. But with your post ill probably manage to find the misstake. Thank you.