# What '&' stands for in "std::vector<byte>& stream;"

Tags: c++, syntax, stl

I know that

```
void foo(vector<int>& v) { ... }
```

is passing vector by reference, but

```
std::vector<byte>& stream;
```

what is that stream variable definition? Why '&' is there?

Comment: It's the same..

Comment: That shouldn't be valid on its own. It's an uninitialized reference.

Comment: @Tomothy32 It's a valid definition for a member variable.

Comment: @robtheblocke, yeah, it's member of class, but why not use just "std::vector<byte> stream;"? Any reasons for that?

Comment: @CinCout Based on what I can see here, it is not the same, both are references to vector of bytes, but first one is a function argument, second is standalone variable.

Comment: @Diodacus There is no difference between parameter types and variable types.

Comment: The `&` is part of the type. Reference types have the same form everywhere, and mean the same thing everywhere.

Comment: A reference means you can modify `stream` and it will update the original `vector` which is passed in, similarly if the original vector is updated `stream` will see those updates to. Also useful for avoiding a copy, if the `vector` was incredibly large

Comment: @Diodacus Essentially, both are *references* to a `vector`, albeit of different types

Comment: @robthebloke Yeah, that's why I said "on its own."

Comment: Class constructor receive vector by reference and assign to private member "stream", so may be '&' is here to avoid copying vector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938113/434551

Comment: Using `vector<int> v` as function parameter means passing the argument by value -> it's copied. Similar, `vector<int> v` as a member of class makes a copy on construction/assignment (or a default construction which leaves it empty). With `vector<int> &v` as function parameter, you get a reference to argument (no copy). `vector<int> &v` as a member must be constructed and stores the reference only (no copy). Concerning the latter, you have to care about life-time of the other instance which reference you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reference to a `std::vector<byte>`. Because it is a reference, it allows you to change the original `vector`, as shown in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Incrementer {
public:
    Incrementer(std::vector<int>& v) : vec(v) {}
    void increment() {
        for (auto& i : vec)
            ++i;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int>& vec;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Incrementer inc(numbers);
    for (auto i : numbers)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    inc.increment();

    for (auto i : numbers)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`inc` will hold a reference to `numbers`, so calling `inc.increment()` changes `numbers`:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 4):

As others said, both of these two are the references. However, the second one is not valid as there is no referenced variable!
It should be written in some way like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> stream1(5);
    stream1[0] = 10;
    std::vector<int>& stream2 = stream1; // stream2 and stream1 are two names for the same variable
    stream1[0] += 55;
    cout << "stream1: " << stream1[0] << endl;
    cout << "stream2: " << stream2[0];
    return 0;
}
```